# Pass extra params in DRF serializer class

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to pass arguments **table_name** and **serial_class** to the serializer class, but `request.data_name` says `Name error : request is not defined`

```
http://localhost:8000/get_data??format=json&table_name=something&serial_class=OrdersDataSerializer
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong

**views.py**

```
class get_data(generics.ListAPIView):
    table_name = eval(request.GET.get('table_name')) # NOT WORKING
    serial_class = eval(request.GET.get('serial_class')) # NOT WORKING

    start = table_name.objects.values("start_date").order_by("-start_date")[0]['start_date']
    end = table_name.objects.values("end_date").order_by("-end_date")[0]['end_date']
    queryset = table_name.objects.filter(start_date=start,end_date=end)
    serializer_class = serial_class
```

**serializer.py**

```
class OrdersDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = orders_data
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: DRF document says that you should use request.get_parmas instead of request.GET.get

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params

Can you please try using request.get_params

Comment: @AashayAmballi i tried it and still getting the same error `NameError: name 'request' is not defined
`

Comment: @AashayAmballi i did this https://i.imgur.com/c8AECuS.png and now i am getting `get_data should either include a serializer_class attribute, or override the get_serializer_class() method.
`

Comment: As mentioned in the DRF tutorial and in your error you need to add a `serializer_class` attribute to your class.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#using-mixins

Comment: @Zat42 `serializer_class` is already added in the last line `serializer_class = serial_class` Am i missing something here?

Comment: It should be define at the root of your class, not in the `get_query` function

Comment: @Zat42 , I am getting the `serializer_class` via params from `serial_class = eval(request.query_params.get('serial_class'))` so i cannto write outside the function, can you please if there is any other way? because `serializer_class` is dynamic for me in this case

Comment: @Zat42 if i write `serializer_class = eval(request.query_params.get('serial_class'))` at the root...it is throwing error as `NameError: name 'request' is not defined` which is why I was forced to write it inside the function

Comment: Yes, because `request` is not defined outside your function. I am not sure there is a way to do what you want. The obvious way to do it is to create a endpoint for each model you need to query

Comment: okay. thanks will do that